# iPhone4 iOS5 Advanced ScrollView techniques: drag and drop a button with longpress

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, iphone-4

I remember that one of the WWDC 2011 videos that dealt with scrollview had a demo, where the presenter (Eliza) demonstrated how to infinitely scroll along a scrollview. The demo used a bunch of pre-generated houses and the moon.

Here's the link to the slides, but I do not see the houses demo, or related code. 
http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/104_advanced_scroll_view_techniques.pdf

here's the code that they have available, but this is not the demo with the houses and the moon: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

The thing that interests me from that demo is how Eliza was able to pick up the moon with a long press and position it anywhere on the UIScrollView. I would like to add a similar technique to my app.

I've checked the source code for the advanced scrollview techniques, and it does not have that example.

**Can anyone help me find out how to pick up a UIControl and drag and position it anywhere within a hosting view using longpress?**

Update:

I found this code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(draggedOut:withEvent: ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragOutside | UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

- (void) draggedOut: (UIControl *) c withEvent: (UIEvent *) ev {

    c.center = [[[ev allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.markerView];
}
```

This picks up and positions the button, however, the button also gets activated as a result of the touch. The drag event begins almost immediately, while I would like to have at least a second of delay and a scaling effect to indicate that the button has been selected.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe subclassing UIButton will help you
[On Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

Or on [Isignmeout](http://www.isignmeout.com/adding-long-tap-functionality-uibutton/) are tutorials for that.

Comment: This is getting closer. I do remember that the code used a long press recognizer, and it probably dropped the UIControl when the gesture ended. What I'm having trouble recalling is whether it used a single gesture recognizer or a combination of long press with something else