# Count button event

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do I do two action on button click event.For example on single click I do one action and on two clicks continuously I have to do another event.

Comment: use touch or use double tap gesture on an imageview ...

Comment: See this SO discussion for some tips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event

Comment: use and find tap gesture you can get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional `setAction:`

If single touch then call `selectorSingleTouch`.

else call `selectorDoubleTouch`.

//this is not compiler checked... atleast you may get some idea from this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double tap gesture ..... on a `UIImageView` . Dont forget to set the `UIImageView's` UserInteractionEnabled to **TRUE**.

```
ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here **tapCount** is `int` variable that declare in **.h file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  tapCount = 0; // Count tap on Slider 

 UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonTap:)];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    
}

 - (void)ButtonTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g 
    {
/////////////// For TapCount////////////

        tapCount = tapCount + 1;
        NSLog(@"Tap Count -- %d",tapCount);

/////////////// For TapCount////////////



if (tapCount == 1)
{

       // code for first tap
}
else if (tapCount == 2)
{
      // Code for second tap
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your initial button tag to 0

then

```
-(IBAction)yourBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (btn.tag==0)
    {
        btn.tag=1;
        //singlePress
    }
    else if(btn.tag==1)
    {
        //double tap

        //if you want other action then change tag
        btn.tag=2;

        //if you restart task then
        btn.tag=0;
    }

}
```