# How would you program a Continuous Delete Button?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I'm making a calculator app and am supplying my own keypad with UIButtons. I have a delete key and everything works except that the user has to keep pressing the delete key over and over again if they want to delete all.

I was wondering if there is a way to delete everything when the button is held for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: This is missing important details. How do you store the number? How do you currently delete the last digit?

Comment: When the user pressed a number key, it will put into a UILabel at the top and the delete key just deletes one character from the end of the UILabel.text.

Comment: If you use longpress gesture I hope you may achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way of implementing this would be attaching a long press gesture recognizer to your `[Delete]` button.

Xcode lets you attach long press gesture recognizer in the interface builder. Add it to your button, configure the duration of long press, and connect the handler to `IBOutlet` in the same way that you connect other UI events.

If you would rather do it in code, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179591/335858) shows you how.

Answer (score 2):

Use your own timer function to handle this

```
-(IBAction)buttonHit {
    //here start timer that fires for every 2 seconds and handle deletion method in that
}

-(IBAction)buttonReleased {
   //Stop timer...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't really help me

Comment: better check out this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Answer (score 1):

In your subclassed UIButton, you might want to watch the ["`touchesBegan: withEvent:`" UIResponder method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a) and if it passes a certain threshold of time, then start deleting like crazy (that is, until the ["`touchesEnded: withEvent`" method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded%3awithEvent%3a) gets called).

Comment: Thanks but i haven't subclassed it and would prefer not to