# iOS/Swift: How to implement longPressed action for backButton?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uigesturerecognizer, back

I'm trying to implement a **custom back button** for every ViewController in my app. I want it to have two actions. If the button gets **tapped**, it should behave normally and go up the navigation stack. If the button gets **pressed longer** it should go to a predefined ViewController.

How can I achieve this for only the backbutton in swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton Long Press Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide your default navigation back button and add a custom button this way:

```
import UIKit

class SViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //hide your default back button
        navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)

        //create a new button 
        var myBackButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        myBackButton.addTarget(self, action: "popToRoot:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        myBackButton.setTitle("Back", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myBackButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myBackButton.sizeToFit()

        //create a LongPressGestureRecognizer
        var longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressAction:")

        //add LongPressGestureRecognizer into button
        myBackButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

        var myCustomBackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBackButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem

    }

    //this method will call when you tap on button.
    func popToRoot(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    //this method will call when you long press on button
    func longPressAction(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

        //initiate your specific viewController here.
        println("Long press detected")
    }

}
```

Comment: should I call pushViewController in longPressAction ?

Comment: .popToRootViewControllerAnimated() goes to my very first view instead of the precedent view..

Comment: Feel free to ask another question with more detail..:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32518980/5316757 Check out my new question if you want :)